# Prove that : $\exists(a,b) \in (]-1,1[)^2 : g'(a)=g'(b)=0$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let the function $f$ differentiable twice on the interval $[-1,1]$ with $f(-1)=f(1)=0$

Take the function            $g(x)=f(x)+f(0)(x^2-1)$

Prove that :                         $$\exists(a,b) \in (]-1,1[)^2 : g'(a)=g'(b)=0$$

Comment: Why should we? You haven't provided any thoughts, background, context ..

Comment: Hint: $g(-1)=g(0)=g(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by dxiv, $g(-1)=g(0)=g(1)$, so you can apply the Rolle's theorem on $[-1,0]$ and $[0,1]$.